# Correct way to cite a book in a thesis

Tags: thesis

I ask you this question that will seem trivial but having no experience in this regard and not having found specific information I do not know what to do.

I am writing my master's thesis in Computer Engineering, and sometimes I use short concepts (for example a 10-word sentence) reworking it and adding concepts different from those of a book mentioned in the biography.

My doubt is the following, in the biography can I also insert the books that I have read to deepen the subject without having used the concept of the book within the thesis but which have been useful to me anyway?

Answer (score 2):

You can only put a book or paper in the bibliography if you have cited it in the text, either via a quote or by citing its argument[s], theory/ies, etc.

If it's just *generally* deepened your understanding and you do not quote it or cite its argument[s] it cannot be included in the bibliography. That said, in such a case it can be very easy to work in a citation from it anyway, even if it's just a few words.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking whether you're allowed to do this: the thesis style guide supplied by your university or department should tell you one way or another.  If you're asking whether it's technically possible: if you're using LaTeX+BibTeX, the `\nocite{}` command, placed somewhere in the body of your LaTeX document, will add an item from your BibTeX database to the bibliography without creating an in-text citation.